# Why I get "java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index "?

Tags: oracle, select, jdbc, where-clause

I try to pass number into PrepareStmt, but get this error. I can't understant my problem.

Query:

```
private static final String SQL_FIND_ALL_CALENDARS = "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE idCall > '?';";
```

Function:

```
private List<Calendar> findAll(Connection con) throws SQLException {
        List<Calendar> calendar = new ArrayList<Calendar>();
        PreparedStatement prsmt = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        try {
            prsmt = con.prepareStatement(SQL_FIND_ALL_CALENDARS);
            prsmt.setInt(1, TestOracleJDBC.idCall);
            rs = prsmt.executeQuery();
            while (rs.next()) {
                Calendar calendar2 = extractCalendar(rs);
                calendar.add(calendar2);
            }
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            rs.close();
            prsmt.close();
        }
        return calendar;
    }
```

In other class my parameter:

```
public static int idCall = 1;
```

Comment: Three things: (a) what does your `extractCalendar` method do?  Please edit the question to include it, (b) don't use semicolons in queries, (c) if something did not help, please explain why not.  Explain what you want the code to do and what it is currently doing.

Answer (score 0):

Single quotes (`'`) denote string literals in SQL. When using bind variables you shouldn't surround the `?` with quotes - that would change it into a string literal with a question mark, not a placeholder for binding values.

Just remove it and you should be OK:

```
private static final String SQL_FIND_ALL_CALENDARS =
    "SELECT * FROM calendar WHERE idCall > ?";
    // Here -------------------------------^
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not help me.